# I have a question about Go pointer usage in package bytes

Tags: go

I have a question about a usage of pointer in Go. The link is here: https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#example_Buffer.

In the `type Buffer` section, the first example:

```
type Buffer struct {
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

```
func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer // A Buffer needs no initialization.
    b.Write([]byte("Hello "))
    fmt.Fprintf(&b, "world!")
    b.WriteTo(os.Stdout)
}
```

and then in the

```
func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

I know that the receiver of `func Write` is `(b *Buffer)` then why in the `main()` function, after declaring/initializing `b`, we can simply use `b.Write()` but **not** **`(&b).Write()`**?

Thank you!

Comment: The compiler can take the address automatically and does this for you. See the `t.M2()`example in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors and the end of https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls. This has nothing to do with package bytes but works on every type.

Comment: @Volker thanks a lot. very useful links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiver is a pointer, and in b.Write(), b is addressable. So Write is invoked on a pointer to b, not a copy of b. If b was not addressable, then you'd have received a compile error. For instance, this would fail:

```
bytes.Buffer{}.Write([]byte{1})
```

In general: you can call methods with pointer receivers only if you can take the address of the receiver object. The compiler passes the reference, not the copy for such methods.

Comment: Go does not have references. The compiler passes a pointer to the value.